# UTF-8 vs ISO-8859-1 when accepting Spanish characters as input on browser

Tags: encoding, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I am building a java based web application. This application accepts English and Spanish accent characters from the user on the browser. If I use character encoding UTF-8 on JSP, all of the Spanish accent chars (áéíóúüñ) will be changed to different symbols (Ã¡Ã©Ã­Ã³ÃºÃ¼Ã±) on server side. But when I use ISO-8859-1 encoding then all the Spanish accent chars will remain as is on server side. I think I should use ISO-8859-1 encoding however all over the places on web it is written use UTF-8 encoding to fix this kind of issue. I am not sure which encoding should I use. And If I to be use UTF-8 then how to fix above issue?

Thanks in advance.